# When is Isolated scope bound to parent scope in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

At what stage of the compile / link process are variables from the isolated scope of a directive bound to the parent (controller) scope? I have an application in which I want to call a directive api automatically, as soon as the view is loaded.

I understood that scope binding [happens in the directive linking phase](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/docs/api/ng.$compile), so that post linking, the variables exposed on the isolated scope should be available on the parent scope.

However, I find that this is not the case, as demonstrated in the code below ([plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNQvc7rD4VFjDzdqePOG)).

```
//plunker code
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.buttonClick = function() {
    console.log("In buttonClick function, call is: " + this.call);
    this.call();
  }

  $scope.$on("LinkComplete", function(event) {
    console.log("In LinkComplete, call is: " + event.currentScope.call);
    //event.currentScope.call();
  });

  console.log("In Constructor, call is: " + this.call);
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      myMethod: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.myMethod = function() {
        alert("method called");
      };
    },
    link: function postLink(scope) 
    {
        scope.$emit("LinkComplete");
    }
  };
});

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div my-directive my-method="call"></div>
  <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Call</button>
</body>
```

Note that the code attempts to access the linked variable (which points to a method on the directive controller) twice during the view initialisation, and on both occasions, the variable is undefined. I wouldn't expect the variable to be available during the main controller constructor, but I would expect it to be available during the post-link event handler. Once the view is loaded, the bound variables are available (click Call button to witness).

How can I access the bound variables from the controller, without requiring the user to click on a button or the like?

Comment: Ok, I could have stated that more clearly (have edited to that effect). I meant when the variables from the isolated scope are bound to the parent scope.

Comment: @pixelbits why not? O thout it is 2 way binding. If you change it in isolated scope it will change it in parent scope to, will it?

Comment: @pixelbits If you run the code and click the Call button, you will see that the controller has access to the myMethod() function on the directive controller, via a scope variable called call. That proves that the two-way binding I want set up is set up correctly. My question is *when* in the compile process is the binding accessible?

Comment: @pixelbits See the section on Scope here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. If what you say is true, the variable still wouldn't be bound in the buttonClick() controller method, but it is.

Comment: You have a point. There is something to what you're saying that I don't understand. It goes against the way that I expected the bindings to work, but your plunker demonstrates that it does behave that way - i'll shut up now:)

Comment: @pixelbits thanks for looking at the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question, when you see some words like 'x is y in z stage' you need to be careful on the accuracy, always dig into the source code to prove it.

Your plunker is using v1.2.27, checkout this line:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.27/src/ng/compile.js#L1492

```
isolateScope.$watch(function parentValueWatch() {
  var parentValue = parentGet(scope);
  if (!compare(parentValue, isolateScope[scopeName])) {
    // we are out of sync and need to copy
    if (!compare(parentValue, lastValue)) {
      // parent changed and it has precedence
      isolateScope[scopeName] = parentValue;
    } else {
      // if the parent can be assigned then do so
      parentSet(scope, parentValue = isolateScope[scopeName]);
    }
  }
  return lastValue = parentValue;
}, null, parentGet.literal);
```

This will be evaluated in next $digest cycle and by then `parentScope.call` will be assigned. At the same time, postLink function is executed synchronously right below it:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.27/src/ng/compile.js#L1575

```
// POSTLINKING
for (i = postLinkFns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  try {
    linkFn = postLinkFns[i];
    linkFn(linkFn.isolateScope ? isolateScope : scope, $element, attrs,
      linkFn.require && getControllers(linkFn.directiveName, linkFn.require, $element, elementControllers), transcludeFn);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e, startingTag($element));
  }
}
```

After postLink has been executed, controller got the event but `parentScope.call` has not been initialized yet via $digest.

So if you add a setTimeout to check, it looks like what you want:

```
$scope.$on("LinkComplete", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("In LinkComplete, call is: " + event.currentScope.call);
        //event.currentScope.call();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks that works! I didn't know that the $timeout/setTimeout(callback) function waits until the current digest cycle is complete before executing the callback. Nor is it in the docs, but it appears to work that way.